# Free Web vulnerability analyzer and crawler (Windows)

Tags: web-application, windows, vulnerability-scanners

I like to know what are the Free Web Vulnerability scanning tools available for Windows.Tools like Netsparker are pretty good but super expensive. I know there are pretty good tools in Kali Linux. What are the good Free Web Vulnerability scanning tools available for Windows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does it have to be windows? You could easily spin up a kali VM and work from there if installing Kali is not an option. OWASP ZAP, one of the most popular, is written for Java so it will run fine on windows. But if using kali is too much of a hassle, i'd skip web application crawlers, pointing it to a website without approval is illegal and can for example leave hundreds of messages in their inbox if the contact form is not configured correctly

Comment: Hi J.A.K, Thanks for your feedback. The situation is, I need to test our own Application which we developed inside the office premises. So Plug-in a Kali machine(or a VM) is not practical. We are running in Windows environment and that is why I need a tool which run on Windows.